# FileUpload.PostedFile.SaveAs() not working on live website asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, save-as, server.mappath

I have a form in a website that does 2 simple things.

1. rename the file
2. route the file to one of 4 specific folders in a server.

The code works perfectly when I run it inside Visual Studio, however, once it goes live it just doesn't work. I do not get any errors or exceptions. I've added some scripts to further debug and I have narrow the problem to the part where the SaveAs() is invoked. My guess is that it has to do with the actual server path once the site is live. I have tried using both the Server.MapPath() and just a straight physical path, but no luck. For security purposes, I am not providing the actual physical path with IP Address here, but once again suffice it to say, when I run it locally inside Visual Studio, it works perfectly.

Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    //Server paths.
    private static string masterserverPath = @"\\IPAddress\e$\BatchImport\";
    private static string personalPath = masterserverPath + "HR PersonalFile\\";
    private static string benefitsPath = masterserverPath + "HR Benefits\\";
    private static string workCompPath = masterserverPath + "HR WC\\";
    private static string LOAPath = masterserverPath + "HR LOA\\";
    //values to dynamicaly populate 4 division in subdiv dropdown list
    string[] personalSubDivArr = {"Employment Inquiry", "EBI", "W-4", "Driver's Application", "Direct Deposit",
                            "Address Changes", "Name Changes", "Employment Verifications", "New Hire-Rehire Datasheet",
                            "PAF's Status Changes", "Acknoledgement of Wages for NY and CA", "Counseling",
                            "Record of Conversation", "Written Warning-Attachments", "Probationary Counseling-Attachments",
                            "Final Warning", "Final Incident Documentation", "Commendations", "Goals and Objectives",
                            "performance Reviews", "Associate Acknowledgements", "Associate Develepment Programs",
                            "Unemployment", "EEOC forms", "I-9"};

    string[] benefitsSubDivArr = {"Associate Benefits Enrollments", "Dependant Eligibility Verifications", "HIPPA Forms","Physicians Documents",
                            "Repayment Agreements", "Beneficiary forms", "Medical Claims", "Acknowledgement Forms", "Cancellation Forms"};

    string[] WCSubDivArr = {"First Report of Injury", "Workers Comp. Medical Claims", "Adjuster Notes", "Wage Statements Verifications",
                     "State Forms", "Medical Improvement Reports", "Release", "Miscellaneous"};

    string[] LOASubDivArr = {"Request for LOA", "Initial Letter", "Medical Certification", "Approval Letter", "Medical Updates", "Extensions",
                      "Release", "Return Letter", "Notes"};
    string newFileName;


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

//Button1 fires up validations before uploading the file to the server
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        //verify if a file to upload exists
        if (FileUpload.HasFile)
        {
            string fileExtension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload.FileName).ToLower();
            string[] allowedExtensions = {".pdf"};
            for (int i = 0; i < allowedExtensions.Length; i++)
            {
                //make sure document is of appropiate type **pdf in this case
                if (fileExtension == allowedExtensions[i])
                {
                    //make sure none of the fields are empty
                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(LnameTextBox.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(FnameTextBox.Text)
                        || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SSNTextBox.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(FileNoTextBox.Text)
                        || SubDivDropDownList.Text == "Select an option" || MasterDropDownList.Text == "Select an option")
                    {


                        UploadMssgLabel.Text = "Employee and Document info cannot be empty.";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    //string to rename file
                        newFileName = (FnameTextBox.Text + " " + LnameTextBox.Text + " " +  SubDivDropDownList.Text 
                                        + " " + "FileNo-" +FileNoTextBox.Text + fileExtension);
                    Response.Write("<script>alert('Inside save');</script>");
                        try
                        {

                            //select which path to save the file to
                            string destinationPath;
                            switch (MasterDropDownList.Text)
                            {
                                case "Personal":
                                    destinationPath = personalPath;
                                    break;

                                case "Benefits":
                                    destinationPath = benefitsPath;
                                    break;

                                case "WorkersComp":
                                    destinationPath = workCompPath;
                                    break;

                                case "LOA":
                                    destinationPath = LOAPath;
                                    break;

                                default:
                                    destinationPath = null;
                                    break;
                            }

                        Response.Write("<script>alert('Saving "+ newFileName +"');</script>");
                        FileUpload.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(destinationPath) + newFileName); //I have tried with Server.MapPath() an without it
                        UploadMssgLabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                        UploadMssgLabel.Text = "Upload Successful!";

                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            Response.Write("<script>alert('" + ex.Message + "');</script>");
                        }
                    Response.Write("<script>alert('ending save');</script>");
                }

                }
                else
                {

                    UploadMssgLabel.Text = "Cannot accept files of this kind.";
                }
            }

        }
        else
        {

            UploadMssgLabel.Text = "Please select a file.";
        }

}

protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Clear the subdiv dropdown every selection. Otherwise, items would just keep being added on
    SubDivDropDownList.Items.Clear();

    //switch to dynamicaly populate the subdiv dropdown
    switch (MasterDropDownList.SelectedValue)
    {
        case "Personal":
            populateDropDown(SubDivDropDownList, personalSubDivArr);
            break;

        case "Benefits":
            populateDropDown(SubDivDropDownList, benefitsSubDivArr);
            break;

        case "WorkersComp":
            populateDropDown(SubDivDropDownList, WCSubDivArr);
            break;

        case "LOA":
            populateDropDown(SubDivDropDownList, LOASubDivArr);
            break;

        default:
            SubDivDropDownList.Items.Add("Select an option");
            break;

    }
}

//Method to populate a dropdown with an array
private void populateDropDown(DropDownList list, Array arr)
{
    list.Items.Add("Select an option");

    foreach (string s in arr)
    {
        list.Items.Add(s);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: You're probably getting an exception, but not noticing it because `ex.Message` is not valid in a string literal.

Comment: @Slaks Nop, I took it out of the literal and used a simple Response.Write() but I still don't get any exception. Any other suggestion to make sure I am not getting an exception?

Comment: You can always try "Response.Write(ex.ToString) and check it client side. log it or whatever - numerous ways to do it.  Or conversely, Response.Write(Server.MapPath(destinationPath) + newFileName)); and without the MapPath, to make sure there isn't a problem with the actual filename/path.  Perhaps it's an IIS setting or something.  You can check if it's accessible, etc, and just pass everything back in a Write to see it client side.

Comment: @Aaron Thank u! finally figured it out with your suggestion. Turns out it wasn't my code. You were absolutely right. The admin messed up the settings in the IIS. If you copy paste your comment as a response I will definitely give you the credit. Thanks!!

Comment: Np, I'm glad you got it.  I work with Azure, I troubleshoot from the client all the time...  I'll post as an answer when I get home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(originally a comment, slightly formatted)

You can always try

```
Response.Write(ex.ToString)
```

and check it client side. log it or whatever - numerous ways to do it. Or conversely,

```
Response.Write(Server.MapPath(destinationPath) + newFileName));
```

and without the MapPath, to make sure there isn't a problem with the actual filename/path.

Perhaps it's an IIS setting or something. You can check if it's accessible, etc, and just pass everything back in a Write to see it client side